# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when mocking MockMultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit4, spring-test

I am mocking up MockMultipartHttpServletRequest as below. Could you please tell me what causes this  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when I just debug this single test case.

```
@ActiveProfiles("development")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:asia/embla/fre/test/config/service-context.xml",
        "classpath:asia/embla/fre/test/config/data-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class BIMDrawingServiceTest {
    //private String ifcFilePath        = "resources/Famacweb-Architect-2016-07-04.ifc";

    @Autowired
    private BIMDrawingService bimService;

    @Test
    public void manageUpload(){
        try {                   
            //MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "Famacweb-Architect-2016-07-04.ifc", "text/plain", new FileInputStream(ifcFile));
        MockMultipartHttpServletRequest  request = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();

         // assertEquals("File name should be equal", "", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you "mocking up MockMultipartHttpServletRequest"? It only appears that you are instantiating it.

Comment: Show us the stack trace with the actual error.